# Selenium Python Tear Down for Safari. How do you handle this?

Tags: python, selenium, safari

So my setup for running Safari .py tests is a little different than those for Chrome and FireFox (examples below). That being said, the `tearDown` for Safari must be different, but I cannot find any examples or figure it out.

Chrome setup example:

```
class ChromeAllLinks(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://test.foo.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
```

Safari setup example:

```
class SafariAllLinks(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        import webbrowser
        browser = webbrowser.get('safari')
        browser.open("https://test.foo.com/")
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
```

So of course the `tearDown` for them should be different as well.

Chrome `tearDown` being used (which works fine of course):

```
def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
```

And I can show what I am trying for the Safari `tearDown`, but it isn't working:

```
def tearDown(self):
    browser = webbrowser.quit('safari')
```

Here is the error being thrown. Says not defined, but it is!

> NameError: global name 'webbrowser' is not defined

Comment: I believe it's probably a typo, `browser.quit` instead of `webbrowser.quit`.